# Significance of 式 in ねずみ算式に増える

Tags: grammar, words

Reading a manga at the moment and I encountered the following sentence:

オスといると、それこそネズミ算式に増えちゃいますから

If ねずみ算 means to 'multiply like rats' what is the significance of adding 式に増える?

I am also confused of what 式 actually means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This 式 on its own has a meaning of "manner" or "style". It is a common suffix used with a noun. ねずみ算 is just a noun, and 式 turns it to a no-adjective.

- [Usage of the suffixes 流, 風, 式, 的 and 様](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3905/5010)
- [What does 五月雨式 means in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40767/5010)
- [I'm wrestling with the first って in 借金が雪だるま式に増えてってるって噂だよ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61730/5010)